# Having trouble storing values from my database in a list in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

As the title states, I am currently trying to store values from my database in a list. In SSMS I have verified that my query pulls the data that I require, but when it comes to vb.net and putting those values into a list it appears to be failing.  Below I have copied the code I am currently working with.

```
            Try
                Dim sb As New StringBuilder
                With sb
                    .Append("SELECT TypeID FROM EnrollmentType AS a ")
                    .Append("INNER JOIN Enrollment AS e ON a.TypeDescription = e.EnrollmentType ")
                    .Append("WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber")
                End With
                Using connEType As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Blah").ToString)
                    Using cmdEType As New SqlCommand(sb.ToString, connEType)
                        cmdEType.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", strgAccountNum)
                        connEType.Open()
                        Using sdrEType As SqlDataReader = cmdEType.ExecuteReader
                            If sdrEType.HasRows Then
                                While sdrEType.Read
                                    For i = 0 To dtEType.Rows.Count - 1
                                        listEType.Add(dtEType.Rows(i).Item("TypeID"))
                                    Next
                                End While
                            End If
                        End Using
                        connEType.Close()
                    End Using
                End Using
                lblSKUDescription.Text = dtEType.Rows.Count
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
                lblSKUDescription.Text = "Oops"
            End Try
```

Even though in SSMS my query works, here nothing is added to the list and my datatable has no rows of data. This piece of code is currently in the page load event because I figure I would want this list populated as soon as possible, I don't know if this matters.
I would also note that there is another sql connection in the page load event, however I have changed any variable names that would be conflicting, I don't know if this matters either, but felt I would mention it.

Any and all help in this matter would be greatly appreciated and if I need to supply additional information I can.

Comment: So the first question is _appears to be failing_.  Could you expand on what this means?  Not returning any data, exceptions, unexpected data or something else.  Next thing I would mention is Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountNumber", strgAccountNum).  Can't confirm types etc just taking a stab based on the names.  strgAccountNum is a string, AccountNumber is a number type.  AddWithValue will be doing an implicate type conversion to string which could cause unpredictible results.  Much more secure to use parameters.Add() and specify the data types

Comment: @Hursey, to expand upon the 'appears to be failing' portion, while in SSMS the values are returned, in VB.net no values are returned. The rows.count for my data table returns 0 and the list.count for my list also returns 0. No exceptions are thrown that I can see. You are correct that strgAccountNumber is a string, but AccountNumber is also a string, it is pulled from a text box I have on the page. I have also confirmed that the text box responsible for AccountNumber is set appropriately. I hope this adds additional clarity to the problem.

Comment: You are using this variable _dtEType_ to fill the list _listEType_ but where do you load rows in that table? If you use that table then why do you loop over the reader ignoring anything present in that reader? It seems a big typo to me.

Comment: Might still be worth trying  Parameters.Add("@AccountNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strgAccountNum rather than AddWithValue.  Other than that the only thing I can see possible is strgAccountNum isn't what you expect it to be

Comment: @Hursey, I'm still having the same problem, however I have added a note regarding your response and will use that while testing as I try to work towards a solution.  I would like to thank you for your help regardless.

Comment: @Steve, I want to thank you for pointing that out. After loading the dtEType, it is now pulling the rows of data I require.  It was a huge typo and from what I can tell things are working nominally now. Kudos to you sir and I thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you are not actually using the `sdrEType` reader, instead you are just using the `dtEType` datatable, which hadn't been loaded. It's unclear why the `For` loop was necessary in the first place.

- You should use a multi-line string, rather than a `StringBuilder`, it;s much clearer.
- The `Catch` makes no sense, as the `Throw ex` wipes the stack trace, and does not run the following line. You should just remove it. If you really need the `Catch`, use `Throw` not `Throw ex`
- `If sdrEType.HasRows` is unnecessary, the `While` will sort that out.
- `connEType.Close()` is unnecssary, the `Using` will do that.
- Specify parameter types and lengths explicitly.
- Qualify each column in the SQL with its table alias/prefix.

```vb
Dim query As String = "
SELECT a.TypeID
FROM EnrollmentType AS a
INNER JOIN Enrollment AS e ON a.TypeDescription = e.EnrollmentType
WHERE e.AccountNumber = @AccountNumber;
"

Using connEType As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Blah").ToString)
    Using cmdEType As New SqlCommand(query, connEType)
        cmdEType.Parameters.Add("@AccountNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = strgAccountNum
        connEType.Open()
        Using sdrEType As SqlDataReader = cmdEType.ExecuteReader
            While sdrEType.Read
                listEType.Add(sdrEType("TypeID"))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
lblSKUDescription.Text = dtEType.Rows.Count
```

Comment: Thanks for this, while I managed to get it working yesterday, this is a much more concise way of doing it. Thank you for your input.